# how to add two NICs in kvm-qemu paramter

Tags: qemu

I can work with one NIC using below scripts in qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name Android11 \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host,-hypervisor \
-smp 8,sockets=1,cores=8,threads=1 \
-m 4096 \
-net nic,macaddr=52:54:aa:12:35:02,model=virtio \
-net tap,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no,vhost=on \
--display gtk,gl=on \
-full-screen \
-usb \
-device usb-tablet \
-drive file=bliss.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio \
...
```

but now, i want to add another NIC to VM for some purpose, when i use below script, it does not work:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name Android11 \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host,-hypervisor \
-smp 8,sockets=1,cores=8,threads=1 \
-m 4096 \
-net nic,macaddr=52:54:aa:12:35:02,model=virtio \
-net tap,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no,vhost=on \
-net nic,macaddr=52:54:aa:12:35:03,model=e1000 \
-net tap,ifname=tap2,script=no,downscript=no \
--display gtk,gl=on \
-full-screen \
-usb \
-device usb-tablet \
-drive file=bliss.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio \
...
```

how can i do when i want to work with the two Nics? is these something wrong in qemu parameters? thanks

PS: i have create tap1 tap2 in linux bridge before using above command